# $a+b+c=10, a,b,c>0$. What is the maximum value for abc?

Tags: calculus, nonlinear-optimization

I have seen many solutions using AM-GM relationships but I am not quite satisfied with those so here is my (incomplete) attempt at it using calculus.

I defined a plane $x+y+z=10$. The maximum volume of the cuboid lying between the axis planes and this $x+y+z=10$ plane would give us our required answer.

For a particular plane where $z$ is a constant, the plane gets intersected forming a line $x+y=a$, where $a=10-z$, hence a constant. The maximum values of $xy$ is achieved at $x=\frac{a}2, y=\frac{a}2$.

Hence our equation $x+y+z=10$ is reduced to $2x+z=10$. We can say that for maximum values of $x,y,z$ subject to aforementioned constraints, the quadrilateral plane lying between $(0,0,0), (0,0,z), (x,y,z),$ and $(x,y,0)$ will be of the maximum area, which would hence given us the maximum values as $\left(\frac{5\sqrt2}2, \frac{5\sqrt2}2, 10-5\sqrt2\right)$

So the maximum volume should be $125 - \frac{125\sqrt2}2$.

My question was whether the assumption that the vertex would lie on the line $x+y=a$ is wrong?

Instead of taking planes along $z$ axis, we could have chosen $x$ or $y$ axis, but the result would be the same so it would be fine. But there seems to be no minima in my range? How to go for it using calculus?

Comment: You have made an argument that $x$ and $y$ should be equal. It seems like it should be the case that by symmetry, $z$ should also be equal to $x$ (and to $y$).

Comment: "So the maximum area should be 125 - 125*root(2)/2." Aren't you trying to maximize a volume, not an area?

Comment: $\displaystyle f(x) = x^2(10 - 2x) \implies f'(x) = 20x - 6x^2, ~f''(x) = 20-12x. ~$  So, $~f(x)~$ has a local maximum at $~x = \dfrac{10}{3}.$

Comment: How did you conclude that over $x+y=a$,  $\max xy$ is achieved at $x=a/2, y=a/2$? And then, can you not use the same reasoning in 3 dimensions (with $a=10$)?

Comment: @Al.G. Re your 1st question, Calculus not needed.  Simply consider the product $$\left( ~\frac{a}{2} + k ~\right) \times \left( ~\frac{a}{2} - k ~\right).$$  As for your 2nd question, it is unclear (at least to me), whether your symmetry argument is valid.  However, my comment re $f(x) = x^2(10-2x)$ seems simple enough.

Comment: I didn't think about $a/2\pm k$, that's nice! But in fact, I was asking *the OP* about the symmetry argument, because I don't know whether *their* 2d argument is easily generalizable to 3d.

Comment: The plane which I mentioned above (essentially cuts the volume in half) should have been of the maximum area for the maximum value of $x, ,y$ and $z$. But it doesn't seems like it? Logically they are directly proportional to the dimensions so should have been the case but isn't????